# Date time picker is not loading after posting the page using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Anybody can help me on this

This is my function;

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (theDate) {
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 9999);
        },
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="add-ctct-activity-date-time">
    <h4>Date</h4>
    <div>
        <input type="text"  id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="add-ctct-activity-date-textbox" style="width:141px"/>
        <span style="position: relative; top: -7px; right: 43px;" class="add-ctct-activity-date-icon"></span>
    </div>
    <span><div id="WarningAddDate" class="textbox-warning-div-date"></div></span>
</div>
```

When click the text box the datepicker is showing good for first time. But, after saving the page using ajax the date time picker is not showing. But it is showing after page load.

This is the ajax code:

```
function SaveEditActivity(strdata, strActId, ActionResult) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: ActionResult,
                data: { Strdata: strdata, StrActId: strActId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#divActivtyShow").html(data);
                    $("#divActivityMenu").show();
                    if (ActionResult == "ComprehensiveAddNewActivity")
                        $('#SpanAddNewActivity').show();
                    $(".success-validate-msg").attr('style', 'display:block');
                    $(".success-validate-msg").html("Great! Contact Updated succussfully");
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    $(".error-validate-msg").attr('style', 'display:block');
                    $(".error-validate-msg").html("Oops! Contact not updated.");
                }
            });
        }
```

Using Jquery I've called the ajax function:

```
$('#divSaveActivitySaveAddNew').click(function () {
            if (!ValidateAddNewActivityFields()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var Ischecked = "0";
                if ($("input[name=chckRemainder]:Checked").val() == "on")
                    Ischecked = "1";
                var strdata = $('#txtsummary').val() + "##$##" + $('#txtdetails').val() + "##$##" + $('#txthours').val() + ":" + $('#txtminutes').val() + " " +     $('#txttime').val() + "##$##" + Ischecked + "##$##" + $('#datepicker').val();
                var strActId = "";
                SaveEditActivity(strdata, strActId, "ComprehensiveAddNewActivity");
            }
        });
```

This is the save button

```
<div id="divComprehensiveEditAddNew" class="m-top" style="display:none">
    <span id="divSaveActivitySaveAddNew" class="blue-btn small-btn">Save</span><span id="btnActivityCancel" class="blue-link"><a href="#"     class="m-left">Cancel</a></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you refresh the `datepicker` input box? i mean are you getting the same in ajax response? if yes, bind `datepicker` event again. Also please use `POST` for saving values not GET

Comment: need more context. please show how AJAX is called at a minimum

Comment: `.attr('style', 'display:block')` is equivalent to `.show()`

Comment: This is the save button

    <div id="divComprehensiveEditAddNew" class="m-top" style="display:none">
        <span id="divSaveActivitySaveAddNew" class="blue-btn small-btn">Save</span><span id="btnActivityCancel" class="blue-link"><a href="#"     class="m-left">Cancel</a></span>
     </div>

Comment: I've added the button code and how its called.

Comment: How to bind datepicker event again?

Comment: Anybody, Please  help me to find the solution, I'm stuck on this.